# I am trying to add RollingFlatFileTraceListener

Tags: trace

I am trying to add RollingFlatFileTraceListener dynamically, It is creating log file but doesnt create new log, After the specified RollSizeKB say 10kb. It is continuosuly adding the data, it just ignore the specified size

```
if (Trace.Listeners["Log Tracing Externally"] == null) {
    Trace.Listeners.Add(
        new RollingFlatFileTraceListener(FileLocation
                                          , ""
                                          , ""
                                          ,new TextFormatter()
                                          , RollSizeKB
                                          ,"yyyy-MM-dd"
                                          , RollFileExistsBehavior.Increment
                                          ,RollInterval.Minute
                                          , 5) { Name = "Log Tracing Externally"  }
                         );             
 }
```